# How to return elements of an arraylist in spring boot?

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-boot

I have made a java application that will do some calculations. It will get some json objects, does some calculations and now i want to produce the output in REST API too. Hence, I am using Spring boot to do so. However, everytime i load the localhost it just returns [], instead of the objects i am looking for. 
here is code.

```
@RestController
public class VehicleController {

    public static void initVehicles() {

        ArrayList<Vehicle> VehicleList = ReadAndParseJSON.parseVehicles();

        //Part One - print in ascending order
        priceOrderAscending(VehicleList);
        //Part Two - based on their SIPP
        getSIPP(VehicleList);
        //Part Three - based on suppliers
        highestRatedSupplier(VehicleList);
        //Part Four - based on score breakdown in descending order.
        scoreBreakDownDescending(VehicleList);
        //Spark.get("/allVehiclesPriceAsc" , (request, response) -> gson.toJson(priceOrderAscending(VehicleList)));
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/allVehiclesPriceASC", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    private static ArrayList<Vehicle> priceOrderAscending(ArrayList<Vehicle> vehicleArrayList) {
        ArrayList<Vehicle> list = new ArrayList<>();
        RentalCarsFormatter.printThePriceAscendingOrder();
        vehicleArrayList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Vehicle::getPrice).reversed());
        for (Vehicle vehicle : vehicleArrayList) {
            System.out.println(vehicle.getName() + " - " + "£" + vehicle.getPrice());
            list.add(vehicle);
        }
        return list;
    }
```

and in the main i do this

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main implements CommandLineRunner{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
        //VehicleController.initVehicles();
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        VehicleController.initVehicles();
    }
}
```

but as i said on when i load the webpage it just shows [].
i try to debug it and it shows the list is empty! but i dont know why!!
Could someone please help me with that? thanks

Comment: I must say when I debug its the vehicleArrayList thats empty!

Comment: Where is the JSON? Shouldn't `priceOrderAscending` get the data from request?

Comment: please add `Vehicle` class and your json data.